# Mixed float and long calculation yields wrong answer with no compiler warning

Tags: java

Is it surprising that the following code outputs a wrong value for startTime?

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       float duration = (float) 2.0;
       long endTime = 1353728995;
       long startTime = 0;
       startTime = (long) (endTime - duration);
       System.out.println(startTime);
}
}
```

Comment: Float cannot accurately represent integers beyond `16777216`  though I suppose it's surprising that long is demoted to float rather than the float being promoted to long

Comment: There would be problems either way. If the calculation were done in long, 1.5f-1L would be zero.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan well yeah but here `2.0` is convertable to long without loss of information. I guess it depends how you look at it?

Comment: @Esailija: It doesn't matter how *we* look at it. The only things that matter are what the language specification says the behaviour should be, and whether the actual behaviour matches that.

Comment: @Esailija I am sure that a series of value-dependent rules would be worse than always converting one way or the other. In this particular case fairly simple flow analysis would tell the compiler the actual value, but the rules have to cover not being able to tell.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yeah I guess you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't output the *wrong* value. It just outputs a value that you don't expect.

The important bit is what happens here:

```
endTime - duration
```

This is *actually* evaluated as:

```
(float) endTime - duration;
```

That's where data is lost. The closest `float` value to 1353728995 is 1353729024, and the closest `float` to the result of subtracting 2 is *still* 1353729024.

This all follows the language specification. [JLS section 15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) (additive operators) states that binary numeric promotions is applied to the operands.

[Section 5.6.2 (binary numeric promotion)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) starts off like this:

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> - If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> - Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>   - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>   - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
>   - ...

So following those rules, the `long` value of `endTime` is converted to `float`, and then the subtraction is performed in `float` arithmetic.

Remember that a `float` only provides 7 significant figures of accuracy, and the rest is fairly obvious, I hope.

Note that without the cast of the result to `long`, the compiler makes it clearer what's going on:

```
Test.java:8: error: possible loss of precision
    long startTime = endTime - duration;
                             ^
  required: long
  found:    float
1 error
```

That makes it fairly clear that the result is going to be a `float`, which should have raised warning bells about how the operation was going to be performed, and what accuracy might be expected.

Comment: Okay, but if I run the code the output is: 1353729024 which seems objectively wrong.

Comment: @Jeff well `float endTime = (float)1353728995L;` means that `endTime` is actually `1.35372902E9`, subtracting `2.0` from that and getting `1353729024` doesn't seem so wrong?

Comment: @Jeff: No, it's objectively correct - if you follow exactly what the language specification says. (What other version of objectivity would make sense here?) It clearly doesn't match your *expectations*, but that's because your expectations don't match the language specification. See my edit - the fact that the closest `float` to 1353728995 is 1353729024 is where the value is coming from.

Comment: Okay, I do understand what is happening. Would a compiler warning be a reasonable expectation?

Comment: @Jeff: No, I don't think so. The fact that you're explicitly casting the result to `long` suggests you already know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

cast floating point to long if you want results in long.

```
 float duration = (float) 2.0;
    long endTime = 1353728995;
    long startTime = 0;
    startTime = endTime - (long)duration;
    System.out.println(startTime);
```

output:

1353728993

If you don't cast, it would be treated as float value and results would be unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

**This is all because of floating point notation.**

When you perform any operation using `float` as at least one of the arguments then the all participating numbers are promoted to `float`. Here your `endTime` is getting converted to `1.35372902E9` as float before the subtraction as this uses `IEEE 754 notation` of exponential representation. **This representation is not very precise and hence you are seeing different result.**

Where as if you do

```
    startTime =  (endTime - (long)duration);
```

Then its operation using long and you should be getting the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

`double` and `float` frequently have a loss in precision. Which likely is what you are seeing here.

Note that you are in fact computing:

```
startTime = (long) ((float)endTime - duration);
```

as the compiler will automatically convert the long into a float for the subtraction. This is well-documented, and some good code checkers will actually warn you of this.

What you probably wanted is this:

```
startTime = endTime - (long)duration;
```

But then you should say so.

You could probably also get the correct by using

```
startTime = (long) (endTime - (double)duration);
```

but this is not *safe* either.